# In SQLAlchemy how do I preview SQL statements before committing for debugging purposes?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to see the SQL code instead of doing an actual db.commit(). This is for a one-off database population script that I want to verify is working as intended before actually making the changes.

Comment: Sir, you have the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Try calling str() on the query object.

```
print query_object.str()
```

From:

[How do I get a raw, compiled SQL query from a SQLAlchemy expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617291/how-do-i-get-a-raw-compiled-sql-query-from-a-sqlalchemy-expression)

Other possible solutions:

- [SQLAlchemy: print the actual query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5631078/sqlalchemy-print-the-actual-query)
- [How to retrieve executed SQL code from SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350411/how-to-retrieve-executed-sql-code-from-sqlalchemy)

The newest (as of v0.9) answer is also:

- [Retrieving ultimate sql query sentence (with the values in place of any '?')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735943/retrieving-ultimate-sql-query-sentence-with-the-values-in-place-of-any/21785653#21785653) (by Mike Bayer)